# Replacing Parts of a Python AST Tree

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, genetic

I'm brand new to using AST, but I've been handed a 'Genetic Programming From Scratch' assignment and from what I can tell AST seems to be the way to go in terms of manipulating the tree.

What I need to do is replace one branch of the tree with one from another tree (in Genetic Programming lingo- 'crossover').

Can anyone advise how best to tackle this? As I say I'm new to AST.

Answer (score 0):

Book [DSLs in Boo: Domain-Specific Languages in .NET](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) of [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/blog) explains AST manipulations in details. He uses [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) language to explain how it works, but AST tree manipulations desccription is pretty generic.